# OpenShift/Kubernetes SDN: Meaning of NetId 0

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, sdn

When I run `oc get netnamespaces`, I get the following lines, among others:

```
NAME                                        NETID      EGRESS IPS
default                                     0          []
kube-service-catalog                        0          []
sandbox-foo                                 9175549    []
```

What is the meaning of `NETID = 0`? Is this a global network, that is accessible for all other projects?

We're running OpenShift 3.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As OpenShift uses  **redhat/openshift-ovs-multitenant** network plugin which means you can control the overlay networks.

All of Pods inside the Project **Default** with **NETID=0**  can access other pods inside the cluster. for example, Router can access the pods from all of the projects  to send the requests.

another example is all of project can list the related images from the docker-registry pod which lives in default project with **NETID=0**

it allow project **Default** to access all pods in the cluster and vice versa

`oc adm pod-network make-projects-global <project1>`

> In the above example, all the pods and services in  and  can now access any pods and services in the cluster and vice versa.

Here is the instruction, how you can make any project a global project [making-project-networks-global](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/managing_networking.html#making-project-networks-global)